# How to make user defined function descriptions ("docstrings") available to julia REPL?

Tags: julia

How can user defined functions (say `f`) have meaningful printouts when inspected via the REPL using `?f`or `help(f)`

For example imagine I write the following funciton

```
function f(x::Float64, y::Float64)
    return 2x - y^2
end
```

If I load this into a julia session and try `help(f)` I get the following:

```
julia> help(f)
f (generic function with 1 method)
```

What if instead I wanted to see something like

```
julia> help(f)
f

   Compute 2 times x minus y squared
```

where the description "Compute 2 times x minus y squared" is written somewhere. I am guessing the answer to my question can be determined from the answer to the question "Where is the somewhere the description should be written?"

---

By way of example, if I wanted to do the same in python, I could define the function and put the description as a docstring:

```
def f(x, y):
    """
    Compute 2 times x minus y squared
    """
    return 2 *  x - y ** 2
```

which would make my description immediately available when I type `help(f)` or `f?` from IPython.

Comment: I don't think you can do that yet. See for example: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/3988

Comment: This will be happening soon. See discussion [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/8514)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the [`@doc`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/documentation/#Advanced-Usage-1) macro in Julia versions 0.4 (Oct. 2015) and above.

```
% julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "?help" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.4.0 (2015-10-08 06:20 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

julia> @doc """
       Compute 2 times x minus y squared.
       """ ->
       function f(x::Float64, y::Float64)
           return 2x - y^2
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @doc f
  Compute 2 times x minus y squared.
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by @Harrison Grodin, versions 0.5 and above support an abbreviated syntax as well as Markdown, LaTEX, and a few other goodies:

```
"""
Calculate the left Riemann sum[^1] approximating ``\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a).``

[^1]: Thomas G., Finney R. (1996), Calculus and Analytic Geometry, Addison Wesley, ISBN 0-201-53174-7
"""
function rs(a, b, d, f)
end
```

There are more details [in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/).

Answer (score 34):

In Julia v0.5+ (*including more recent Julia Versions like 1.2+*), you can write a multiline string above the function definition. (No need for `@doc` anymore.)

````
julia> """
           cube(x)

       Compute the cube of `x`, ``x^3``.

       # Examples
       ```jldoctest
       julia> cube(2)
       8
       ```
       """
       function cube(x)
           x^3
       end
cube

help?> cube
search: Cdouble isexecutable Ac_mul_B Ac_mul_Bc Ac_mul_B! Ac_mul_Bc! cumsum_kbn

  cube(x)

  Compute the cube of x, x^3.

     Examples
    ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> cube(2)
  8
````

For more information on properly formatting your docstrings, see the official [Julia Documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/documentation/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Julia 1.7: I type `"""<ENTER>My function<ENTER>"""<ENTER>` - and this gets evaluated as the string `"My function\n"`, so I don't get a chance to input the actual function definition...

Comment: In the REPL, press <ALT>-<ENTER> (or <OPTION>-<ENTER>) to create the final newline.

Comment: <ALT><ENTER> does not work in my Windows REPL: it turns the REPL full-screen instead. (That's a cmd feature.)