# Example usage of Docile.jl in Julia 0.3

Tags: julia, documentation-generation

I'm new to Julia.  I'm interested in using [Docile.jl](https://michaelhatherly.github.io/Docile.jl/index.html) to add documentation to an existing Julia project. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821247/how-to-make-user-defined-function-descriptions-docstrings-available-to-julia), docstrings have already been added to Julia 0.4, but I'd like to get docstrings working in 0.3.

The example in the post above doesn't work in 0.3, though.  `help(f)` doesn't show the docstring, and `@doc f` returns an error.  Can someone help me see what is missing?

```
$ julia
               _
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.6 (2015-01-08 22:33 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org release
|__/                   |  x86_64-linux-gnu

julia> using Docile

julia> @doc """
              Compute 2 times x minus y squared.
              """ ->
              function f(x::Float64, y::Float64)
                  return 2x - y^2
              end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> help(f)
INFO: Loading help data...
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @doc f
ERROR: @doc: use `->` to separate docs/object:
(:f,)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use Docile.jl in conjunction with [Lexicon.jl](https://michaelhatherly.github.io/Lexicon.jl/index.html). The session below shows that if you just document functions without `using Lexicon`, help text for any function won't change. The help text only reflects your documentation once you type `using Lexicon`. Note that, below, I'm getting help text by typing a `?` at the repl, not by using the function `help`.

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.6 (2015-02-17 22:12 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

julia> using Docile

julia> 

julia> @doc """
                            Compute 2 times x minus y squared.
                            """ ->
                            function f(x::Float64, y::Float64)
                                return 2x - y^2
                            end
f (generic function with 1 method)

help?> f
INFO: Loading help data...
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> using Lexicon

help?> f
f (generic function with 1 method)

INFO: Parsing documentation for Docile.
INFO: Parsing documentation for Lexicon.
INFO: Parsing documentation for Docile.Interface.

[method]

.f(x::Float64, y::Float64)

  Compute 2 times x minus y squared. 

 Details:

    source: (3,"none")
```