# docstrings in Juno

Tags: julia, docstring

Today I started learning Julia.
I've tried the following on Juno, running Julia 0.3.8

```
VERSION < v"0.4-" && import Docile
using Docile

@doc doc"""
  Hello Hello ***world***
""" ->
function hello()
  print ("Not bad") 
end
```

With juno, the ctrl+D key-combo just yields the default:

> hello (generic function with 1 method)

The same happens on the terminal with `?`

I've tried out other varieties, for example `@doc """ blah blah """ -> .....` or even `@doc "blah blah" -> .....`.

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.

**edit**
ok, wrapping the function in a module which is then imported makes the docstring work in the repl but the ctrl+d key combination in juno does still not work as before.

Comment: No. It does not work. Not even using Lexicon as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662958/example-usage-of-docile-jl-in-julia-0-3

Comment: (neither in the REPL, nor in Juno)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have posted this question, docstrings have become standard throughout Julia Base and `?function` will return the docstring in both Juno and the REPL.

Comment: Yes. I forgot to close this one. Tnx.